# How can I access library file dependencies in another project after creating a .aar file, but I'm unable to access them?

Tags: android

How can I access library file dependencies in another project after creating a .aar file, but I'm unable to access them?

Like retrofit  ssp sdp

Comment: How did you add the relevant .aar file to your project?